# Swift ios connect multiple items to the same IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, iboutlet

I wonder if its OK to connect multiple items to the same IBOutlet?
In my tableView I have setup two cells and given them a uniqe identifier.

But I have connected the label in each cell to the same IBOutlet in my custom UITableViewCell class.

[image]

```
class SearchSubCatTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  
    @IBOutlet weak var subCatTitle: UILabel!
```

So I have two labels connected to `@IBOutlet weak var subCatTitle: UILabel!`

This all works fine when I am testing the app but can it cause any problems?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is ok **as long as you don't** plan on doing any operations on those labels.

The correct way to do it, is by creating an array IBOutlet:

```
@IBOutlet var collectionOfLabels:[UILabel]?
```

- Connect all your labels to this labels array outlet.
- Then access the labels via the array.

Comment: What do you mean by operations? The only thing I do now is to set a title

Comment: If you set the title once at the interface builder then fine, but if you need to change it later programmatically then that would cause a problem. @user2636197

Comment: Would the app crash? Right now one cell has a static label and the second cell has a dynamic label from JSON data

Comment: Good chances that it will crash at some point, I would suggest not to take the risk and write it in a proper way.

Comment: Is it okay if I loop through these objects, and than do something with it. Like changing the alpha?

Answer (score 1):

**This may cause a problem** when you will try to perform some operations on the label text data.I would suggest you to have a look at `IBOutlet Collections`.You can find nice tutorial [here](http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/).

Answer (score 1):

You can connect multiple view/labels/etc to one `@IBOutlet` while they are from different parents.

Egzample: 
You have one class `HeaderView` with label and imageView, but you have 3 separated xib files which contains `HeaderView` (lets say for 3 kinds of devices (iPhone, iPhone 6Plus, and iPads). You set class of this views as HeaderView and connecting `@IOBoutlets` to one link.

If you want create @IBOutlet collection you have to define your outlet as array of type. For example: `@IBOutlet private var labels: [UILabel]!`

Answer (score 0):

you will not face any problem.i have done same thing many times.while creating cell each property has its own value.so i guess you will not face anyproblem

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't cause any problems.

I used a similar setup in my app and it got accepted into the app store.

Answer (score 0):

you will not face a problem if you connect multiple buttons with the same Outlet. You might face some issues if you try to perform functions on these buttons. I  would suggest you to have a look at using tags if you wish to perform functions on these buttons.